# Regex with ASP.NET validator to allow any text but numbers

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I've tried these two expressions:

```
ValidationExpression="[^0-9]$"
ValidationExpression="^[^0-9]$"
```

But this is marking cities like Phoenix and Denver as having numbers in them. What is the correct expression to use here to only allow text that does not contain numbers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`^[^0-9]*$`

The issue you had there was that you were only matching one character. The asterisk indicates "0 or more matches".